# How to define commutative covariant derivatives in xTensor

Tags: tensors, xact, field-theory

I'm new with working xAct package and got stuck defining covariant derivatives that commute with each other.

I want to simulate flat space-time. And here is my code

```
DefManifold[M4, 4, IndexRange[{a, f}]];
DefCovD[CD[-a], TangentM4, {"|", "\[Del]"}, Curvature -> False, CurvatureRelations -> False]
DefTensor[T[a], M4]
```

The following expression should be equal to zero because there is no curvature and in flat space, covariant derivatives are the normal commutative derivatives. But it does not commute

```
CD[c]@CD[b]@T[a] - CD[b]@CD[c]@T[a] // Simplification
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you have no luck here, try <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/xact>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Covariant derivatives with upper indices do not make sense before introducing a metric. So this works:

```
In[7]:= CD[-c]@CD[-b]@T[a] - CD[-b]@CD[-c]@T[a] // Simplification
Out[7]= 0
```

Instead of Simplification (or ToCanonical) you can also use SortCovDs, which will sort covariant derivatives even if they are not flat, introducing Riemann terms.

You can automate sorting of a covariant derivative with

```
In[8]:= SortCovDsStart[CD]
```

Then you have:

```
In[9]:= CD[-c]@CD[-b]@T[a] - CD[-b]@CD[-c]@T[a]
Out[9]= 0
```

Comment: I've defined metric like this now
`DefMetric[-1, g[-a, -b], CD, {"|", "\[Del]"}, FlatMetric -> True]`
But Covariant derivatives with upper indices still does not commute